# Is there really no unicode for "扌"?

Tags: characters

[（扌+方）的释义--字海网（叶典网）](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=1F2870)

> [image: leng]

Getting `非unicode` but it's kind of hard to believe.

Is there really no unicode for "扌"?

Comment: Where did you find this character? It's probably a rare/regional (southwest) variation of other character, like 楞, 愣 or 塄? (Although the given meaning suggests something different.) Some characters have many different variations, and there are no Unicode for them all, it seems.

Comment: 扌has unicode, but maybe your input is not encoded in unicode. This is not a Chinese question, but a encoding problem. I believe if you ask some computer programmer or I18N engineer, you would get better answer

Comment: Uhhhhh....this is not a question about 扌but about 扌 as a radical with 罒 and 方, so don't really know what you are answering

Comment: When were zisea or yedict last updated? May be the CJK Unified Ideographs Ext. E have this included.

Comment: that's the same problem. you are not asking a question about Chinese, but character encoding. You should ask I18N engineer, but not people learning Chinese

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fear no more, for there is now:

「」

(Unicode: U+2D865)

Comment: I can see most of the Chinese characters on this site but not the one you posted. What do I need to do to have it appear on my English Windows 10?

Comment: @joehua I cannot either. It would take some time (maybe a lot) for fonts to get updated to include these characters. And you may have to manually install them. These characters can only the correctly displayed with appropriate fonts installed.

Comment: @joehua https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/24210/4136

Answer (score 3):

Nothing surprising about it. I too have never seen this character, and the Unicode doesn't record all Chinese characters, by far. Here's what the Unicode tables show:

[image: The main table]

The main table, radical 扌, 9 strokes.

[image: Extension B, part 1]

The Extension B table, radical 扌, 9 strokes.

[image: Extension B, part 2]

The Extension B table, radical 扌, 9 strokes, continued.

As you can see, no 扌罒方 here. So, no Unicode.

Comment: My surprise was that it's collected in 《字海》and a bunch of my old (topolectical) dictionaries all have it

Comment: Sure and if I take my old paper dictionary that has 50k+ characters, it will probably be there. Doesn't have anything to do with Unicode organisation though. Note you said ***old*** dictionaries. Which were printed way before the Unicode was started. Don't assume **all** sinograms have a Unicode...

Comment: Right. It just seemed more commonplace than it must really be to me.

Answer (score 0):

As a native Chinese, I've never learned this character. But I can't tell whether it "really doesn't exist".

I think it's a region-specific-writing-by-mistake creation. People want to express the meaning but don't know there is an existing character for it. Back when communicating with the outside was very difficult, it was a common scenario.

According to the explanation of the character, there is a formal character **捻** to express the same meaning.