# How to display CJK Extension F?

Tags: characters

The CJK F block is displayed on the wikipedia page [CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJK_Unified_Ideographs_Extension_F):

I've tried updating *[Babel Han](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Fonts/Han.html)* but they themselves say:

> Total Coverage
>
> Characters / Percentage
>
> CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F 1,141 / 7,473   15.3%

So, only fifteen percent of Extension F characters are covered in Babel Han.

*[Hanazono](http://fonts.jp/hanazono/)* hasn't been updated in a while and only supports up to **Extension E**.

How can I display the CJK Extension F block in my browser?

Comment: I have same question as yours, I checked latest BabelPad v10.0.0.1 cannot show CJK ext F at my PC too, ^_^。 Unicode release a new version at around June, e.g. v9 at June 2016, v10 at June 2017, now Babel Han is updated to support v10. but "how to display CJK Unified Ideographs Extension F" is not related to Babel Han, it is related to fonts only. basically only CJK + ext A + ext B used by peoples, all other extensions are used by ancient literature, no need to be supported in most scenarios.

Comment: @DanielYeung well, solution is below if you’re interested.

Comment: Just a note that Hanazono covers **CJK extension F** since 2017-09-04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**天珩字库**

[【字海(叶典)】软件下载](http://yedict.com/download/) has a file called:

[天珩全字库V2.0.2(TH-Tshyn)](http://yedict.com/download/TH-Tshyn-2.0.2.zip) (direct link) its description reads:

> 目前字符数量最全的字体支持包，其中汉字部分支持大约12万汉字，主要设计为大陆风格，扩展EF主要为日本风格。另外本字库有Unicode10.0以内的几乎所有字符，包括表情符号(黑白色)。

It contains almost all characters in Unicode 10!

When installed you will be able to display all Ext. F characters, have a look at a sample:

[image: pic]

Answer (score 3):

Just updating the download link from above, which broke.
Since 2017, they've added over 20,000 characters to the font!

[Download page (Traditional Chinese 下載 -繁體版)](http://cheonhyeong.com/Traditional/download.html)

[Download page (Simplified Chinese version 下载-简体版)](http://cheonhyeong.com/Simplified/download.html)

[English version (omits 95% of the links in the Chinese version)](http://cheonhyeong.com/English/download.html)